# How to create a vertical bar inside the right margin on only part of a page

Tags: formatting, geometry

```
\documentclass[english]{book}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ %
%
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} %
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb} %
\usepackage{tikz} % tikz - essential
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %
\usepackage{newtxtext} %
\usepackage{newtxmath} %
\usepackage{xcolor} %
\usepackage{colortbl} % changed to just colortbl
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm,textwidth=132mm,lmargin=12.5mm,rmargin=12.5mm,bindingoffset=12.5mm,noheadfoot,nomarginpar,showframe,showcrop]{geometry} %
\usepackage[a4,frame,cam,center]{crop} 
\usepackage{setspace}
%
% --------------------------------------- START DECLARATIONS --------------------------- %
%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1pt} 
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newenvironment{eq}[2]{%
  \setlength{\mathindent}{#1}%
  \setlength{\hsize}{\dimexpr\hsize-#2\relax}%
  \ignorespaces
}{\ignorespacesafterend}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}

\newcommand\dashfill{\leaders\hbox to 18pt{\hss-\hss}\hskip\fill\hspace{-12pt}}

\begin{document}

\setstretch{1.25}
Using the latest 64-bit versions of Technic Center and MiKTeX 2.9\hspace{2.2pt}\ldots

\vspace{6pt}
How can I create a vertical bar just inside the right margin to draw attention to only \\ a selected mixture of math mode and normal text?

I would like to control its thickness and colour.

\vspace{12pt}
I do not want to include this line of text.

I do not want to include this line of text.

I do not want to include this line of text.

\vspace{6pt}
I want the vertical bar to commence at this level > > >

Some introductory remarks\ldots

\vspace{-24pt}
\begin{eq}{124pt}{24pt}
\begin{equation}
l+m=m+l \dashfill \label{eqn:chap_intro_to_num_02}
\end{equation}
\end{eq}

\vspace{-24pt}
\begin{eq}{106pt}{24pt}
\begin{equation}
(l+m)+n=l+(m+n)\dashfill \label{eqn:chap_intro_to_num_04}
\end{equation}
\end{eq}

Some comment on the equations that I want to include.

I want the vertical bar to cease at this level > > >

\vspace{12pt}
I do not want to include this text.

I do not want to include this text.

I do not want to include this text.


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK one way you can implement the vertical bar is using the help of `tabular` environment. Another way you can tackle the same problem might be by using `tikzpagenodes` package, but someone better than me can help in that case.

So in this particular example I used the `colortbl` package to allow the control of the vertical bar width and the color. The height will be determined automatically by the content you enclose it with the `tabular` environment. I have used `p` as alignment specifier to allow texts to wrap inside the environment and the tabular width is set to `0.95\textwidth`, partly because of the way you define `eq` environment. I have colored the bar `blue`, but you can change however you like and bar width is set to `3pt` via `\vrule width`. So the argument for `tabular` sums up to `p{0.95\textwidth}!{\color{blue}\vrule width 3pt}`. Some dummy texts were added using `lipsum`.

[image: Sample]

The full code is then:

```
\documentclass[english]{book}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ %
%
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} %
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb} %
\usepackage{tikz} % tikz - essential
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %
\usepackage{newtxtext} %
\usepackage{newtxmath} %
\usepackage{xcolor} %
\usepackage{colortbl} % changed to just colortbl
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm,textwidth=132mm,lmargin=12.5mm,rmargin=12.5mm,bindingoffset=12.5mm,noheadfoot,nomarginpar,showframe,showcrop]{geometry} %
\usepackage[a4,frame,cam,center]{crop} 
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{colortbl} % For vertical bar control in tabular environment.


%
% --------------------------------------- START DECLARATIONS --------------------------- %
%

\setlength{\unitlength}{1pt} 
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newenvironment{eq}[2]{%
  \setlength{\mathindent}{#1}%
  \setlength{\hsize}{\dimexpr\hsize-#2\relax}%
  \ignorespaces
}{\ignorespacesafterend}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}

\newcommand\dashfill{\leaders\hbox to 18pt{\hss-\hss}\hskip\fill\hspace{-12pt}}

\begin{document}

\setstretch{1.25}
Using the latest 64-bit versions of Technic Center and MiKTeX 2.9\hspace{2.2pt}\ldots

\vspace{6pt}
How can I create a vertical bar just inside the right margin to draw attention to only \\ a selected mixture of math mode and normal text?

I would like to control its thickness and colour.

\vspace{12pt}
I do not want to include this line of text.

I do not want to include this line of text.

I do not want to include this line of text.

\vspace{6pt}
I want the vertical bar to commence at this level > > >

\begin{tabular}{p{0.95\textwidth}!{\color{blue}\vrule width 3pt}}
Some introductory remarks\ldots

\lipsum[66]

\vspace{-24pt}
\begin{eq}{124pt}{24pt}
\begin{equation}
l+m=m+l \dashfill \label{eqn:chap_intro_to_num_02}
\end{equation}
\end{eq}

\vspace{-24pt}
\begin{eq}{106pt}{24pt}
\begin{equation}
(l+m)+n=l+(m+n)\dashfill \label{eqn:chap_intro_to_num_04}
\end{equation}
\end{eq}

Some comment on the equations that I want to include.

\lipsum[75]

\end{tabular}

I want the vertical bar to cease at this level > > >

\vspace{12pt}
I do not want to include this text.

I do not want to include this text.

I do not want to include this text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: No, I want the vertical bar only to be adjacent to the right margin, but to be able to control its starting level and finishing level. Almost a left-right reflection of what you've done.

Comment: I think you should be clarifying more about the problem than just giving the whole code with some in-code texts. You might want to as for example mention whether the vertical bar height should be dependent on content height or is it independent. And if possible give an illustration as an example.

Comment: M A - it seems clear to me...  I just want a vertical bar to run down the right margin - but not down the complete page - in order to draw attention to a limited amount of text (or math).

Comment: Updated. See if this can solve your problem. Remember that there must be linebreaks before and after the `tabular` environment since it doesn't float.

Comment: That appears to solve the problem perfectly, thanks.